# What's the meaning of "off line"?

Tags: meaning

The following is a verse from Daniel Powter's song [Bad Day](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/danielpowter/badday.html):

> You stand in the line just to hit a new low
>   You're faking a smile with the coffee to go
>   You tell me your life's been way **off line**
>   You're falling to pieces every time
>   And I don't need no carryin' on

What does *off line* mean in the third line of the verse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suggests there is a path that he wants / should follow, and he isn't. It is like not following the best way - he has lost the way.

It is different to meaning they aren't connected to the internet (although not being connected may make some people's lives off line).

Comment: _off line_ has become a metaphor. Interestingly, it's one of the few cases where a computer term has been adapted into mainstream language, rather than an old word being adopted as a computer metaphor (like _desktop_).

Comment: @Barmar yes, it is a strange case - I can't think of many!

Comment: And referring to "life" being offline is an extended metaphor. A more common use is something like _Let's discuss that offline_ when in a meeting, meaning outside the meeting.

Comment: In some offices, "Let's take that offline." in a meeting just means, "Let's stop talking about that."